# How to fix Windows 11 widgets not loading?

Tags: windows-11, widgets

[This is my Widgets view currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/108uT.png)

I recently re-installed Windows 11 Pro and have run into a weird issue. My widgets area just stopped loading altogether.

Upon the first few startups, the Widgets area was loading fine. I started noticing the issue after installing a Windows update that moves the Widgets to the left side of the taskbar.

I have tried...

1. disabling and re-enabling the widget,
2. resetting and reinstalling the Microsoft News app,
3. and playing around with various app permissions through Settings.

At this point I've looked up solutions and verified that my version of WebView2 is the most recent version. None of my actions have affected the Widget area and I'm stumped.

Has anybody else experienced this?

OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000

Comment: Do not play around too much. Normally a restart or wait a day, restart works.

Comment: This has been an issue for a week now and I've updated, restarted, and upgraded to a preview build, but the behavior hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fixes for widgets in Windows 11 (including the ones you did already) :

- Enable Widgets by right-click on the taskbar, select Taskbar settings,
  under Taskbar items toggle on Widgets.
- Restart the Windows Widgets process in Task Manager, Processes tab,
  under Background Processes select Windows Widgets and click End Task.
- Ensure you are logged in with a Microsoft account.
- Set Microsoft Edge as default browser in
  *Settings > Apps > Default Apps*, click the current default browser,
  under `.htm` click again the current web browser,
  choose Microsoft Edge and click OK.
- Install Microsoft Edge WebView2.
- Reinstall Widgets from Microsoft Edge via the
  [Windows web Experience Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MSSGKG348SP).

Comment: I've tried all of these steps to no avail. :(

Comment: I think that the above list contains all the known remedies. As a general remark - for a new operating system, Windows 11 has already accounted for hundreds of posts on our site. My personal opinion is that it was released much too early with many new features still half-done or badly-done. You may wait for an upgrade that will correct the Widgets problem, or do a [Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/). My real advice would be to return to Windows 10, which is rock-steady...

Comment: That's a fair point and I've been considering it. I'll be doing just that, thanks for the advice.

Comment: The last bullet point worked. I had to uninstall the Windows Web Experience Pack using `Winget Uninstall "Windows Web Experience Pack` in Powershell and then just redownloaded it using harrymc's link.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything that I found when I googled and nothing worked.  Then I found a page that referred me to an error message from Visual C++ that is what Widgets is written in.  I downloaded the current redistributable from Microsoft website and viola the widgets icon APPEARS!  Hopefully this helps someone else!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).